# CodeWarrior to program MCF51QE128 Getting "privilege violation" exceptions writing to flash

Tags: flash, volatile, flash-memory, codewarrior

I have an application written in C (new to me) in CodeWarrior. The processor is MCF51QE128.  I am familiar with assembly language in the old MC6809 (8 bit) processors.
The troublesome code is:

```
FSTAT=(byte)(0x30);
asm {
  move.l   D0,0x1f000;       // Dummy address writeVarA_Flash
}//End of asm
FCMD=(byte)(0x40);         // Sector Erase Command (4000 cycles 0f 5 microsec period = 20,000 microsec.
FSTAT=(byte)(0x80);        // Start the command
```

In the .lcf file I have changed the permissions as
    MEMORY {
       code        (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x00000410, LENGTH = 0x0001DBF0
       userram     (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x00800000, LENGTH = 0x00002000
       userrom     (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x0001E000, LENGTH = 0x00000002
    }

The code causes a "Protection Violation" flag to appear in the "FSTAT" register (observed in DeBug) and the program goes into lala land.
The Security is turned off. Is the userrom section still considered as a "protected" area of flash? I need to store volatile integers during power outages.
What am I missing?